# Finger print Bio reader not activated

Tags: hardware

My HP EliteBook has a built in finger bio reader that is not activated, can this hardware be used with Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you post a little more information?  Perhaps the output from `lsusb`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Fingerprint-GUI:

1. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui`

**Warning**

When you install the `policykit-1-fingerprint-gui` package, it will replace/uninstall `policykit-gnome` (or which ever equivalent environment you're using).  Make a note of which is it, so that you can reinstall it if something goes wrong.